# Array empty after firebase read swift

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

So i  have an array AllOrders of type Order, everytime i want to refresh the table i want to empty the AllOrders array to get theinformation from the database fresh.
But the problem is that i am getting always an empty array.

I tried the following solutions:

1. created a delay: this worked when i put the delay up to 42 seconds, but who can wait 42 seconds. come on...
2. searched for a converter of async to sync but didn't find anything.

I know the firebase functions are async which is what is causing my problem.

```
    let userkey = sessionName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    ref.child(userkey).child("handyman-orders").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            let newOrder = Orders()
            newOrder.service = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.image = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "image").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.DeliveryType = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "DeliveryType").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.PickupInfo = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "PickupInfo").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.address = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "address").value! as? String)!
            allOrders.append(newOrder)
        }
        print("handyman  orders recieved")
    })

    ref.child(userkey).child("laundary-orders").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            let newOrder = Orders()
            newOrder.service = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.image = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "image").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.DeliveryType = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "DeliveryType").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.PickupInfo = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "PickupInfo").value! as? String)!
            newOrder.address = (rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "address").value! as? String)!
            allOrders.append(newOrder)
            print("while laundary getorders",allOrders)
        }
        print("Laudanry orders recieved")

    })
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

and my refresh table function is

```
 func refreshtable(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    allOrders.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    getAllOrders()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Anybody has any ideas?
I would highly appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this? Let Firebase refresh the array for you. That will eliminate the need to keep polling Firebase for data. The implementation you have defeats the purpose of a real-time database.

Comment: Could you please tell how that is done.

Comment: That would go beyond the scope of Stackoverflow due to the length. However, Firebase has some nice tools on their website to explain how to work with Firebase observers and events [Firebase Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0) as well as some nifty documentation that covers the topic as well [Work with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) and check out the Listen For Events section.